How to create transparent gradient blur around transparent blurred div?
I have an div element that is transparent but blurs everything behind it, through a combination of backdrop-filter: blur() and rgba(255, 255, 255, 0). You can see an example in this JSFiddle, the code of which is replicated below. Most of this code is from the MDN Docs page for backdrop-filter, with small modifications by myself.
I'd like to make it so that the blurring effect, instead of ending sharply at the border lines of the div, fades out in a gradient (kind of like using a box-shadow with a blur property, but the shadow is invisible and the blur affects whatever's behind it instead).
How can I achieve this effect?
I've looked around for a solution, but I haven't been able to find anyone asking the same question or a way to apply a backdrop-filter directly to a shadow. The only workaround I can think of is creating several transparent divs around the main one, with incrementally increasing sizes and decreasing backdrop-filter: blur() values, to create the illusion of a blur gradient, but that seems quite "hacky" and I'd like to avoid it if there is at all a "cleaner" method.


.box {
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 0%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ec/d8/34/ecd834e40fc5bbd91f3156a2f1823fca.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-size: cover;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>




I don't think you can put a gradient on the blur effect itself, but you can try masking the blurry div


.box {
  --w: 20px; /* Width of the "gradient" */
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  mask: 
  radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at bottom right, #000, #0000) top left/var(--w) var(--w) no-repeat,
  radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at bottom left, #000, #0000) top right/var(--w) var(--w) no-repeat,
  radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at top left, #000, #0000) bottom right/var(--w) var(--w) no-repeat,
  radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at top right, #000, #0000) bottom left/var(--w) var(--w) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(#0000, #000) top/calc(100% - 2*var(--w)) var(--w) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(#000, #0000) bottom/calc(100% - 2*var(--w)) var(--w) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(90deg, #0000, #000) left/var(--w) calc(100% - 2*var(--w)) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(-90deg, #0000, #000) right/var(--w) calc(100% - 2*var(--w)) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(#000, #000) center/calc(100% - 2*var(--w)) calc(100% - 2*var(--w)) no-repeat;
  /* If you div has fixed size you can make the mask image in PS or something and not bother with this monstrosity */
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ec/d8/34/ecd834e40fc5bbd91f3156a2f1823fca.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-size: cover;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
  </div>




Unfortunately, that doesn't quite achieve what I'm trying to do, especially since the border lines of the invisible div become sharp very quickly if I zoom in at all. Lots of testing by myself and others has convinced me that what I'm looking for isn't exactly doable, so I'm just going to redesign in such a way that I don't require that effect. Your answer definitely taught me something new about CSS though. Thanks!
